# Android Intellij build: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, build

I am trying to build an android project via intellij but i get

```
Error:Android Dex: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Does anyone know how can i build a project from intellij that exceeds the 65K methods?

Comment: IntelliJ isn't a Build Tool. Are you using Gradle?

Comment: I use maven as build tool, but when you develop an application you use also the IDE for quick make.